# Uploading File To Azure Storage causes the error: Timeouts are not supported on this stream

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, filestream, azure-blob-storage

I have a form including a file upload to Azure Storage. 
This is where ToStream() method called:

```
 Image img= Image.FromStream(file.InputStream, true, true);
 if (img.Height != height || img.Width != width)
 img= img.GetThumbnailImage(width, height, null, new IntPtr());
 img.ToStream().SaveAsBlob(blobname, filename);
```

And this is ToStream() Method:

```
public static Stream ToStream(this Image image)
{
    Stream ms = new MemoryStream();
    image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    ms.Position = 0;
    return ms;
}
```

Where I get the error is:

```
  image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

The error is

```
'ms.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
'ms.WriteTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
```

Its base is:

```
Timeouts are not supported on this stream
```

Here is SaveAsBlob() Method:

```
public static void SaveAsBlob(this Stream stream, string containername, string blobname)
{
     BlobHelper helper = new BlobHelper();
     CloudBlobContainer container = helper.ContainerGet(containername);
     helper.BlobDelete(container, blobname);
     helper.BlobAdd(container, blobname, stream);
}
```

BlobHelper Class:

```
public class BlobHelper
{
    private const int MaxBlockSize = 4000000;

    private CloudStorageAccount _CloudStorageAccount { get; set; }

    public BlobHelper()
    {
        this._CloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[StaticConfiguration.ConnectionString].ConnectionString);
    }

    public CloudBlobContainer ContainerGet(string adi)
    {
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = _CloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(adi);
        container.CreateIfNotExists();
        BlobContainerPermissions containerPermissions = new BlobContainerPermissions();
        containerPermissions.PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob;
        container.SetPermissions(containerPermissions);
        return container;
    }

    public Uri BlobAdd(string filePath, CloudBlobContainer container)
    {
        byte[] fileContent = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        string blobName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
        return BlobAdd(fileContent, container, blobName);
    }

    public Uri BlobAdd(CloudBlobContainer container, string adi, Stream stream)
    {
        adi = adi.Replace("//", "/");
        byte[] content = new byte[stream.Length];
        stream.Read(content, 0, (int)stream.Length);
        return BlobAdd(content, container, adi);
    }

    public Uri BlobAdd(byte[] fileContent, CloudBlobContainer container, string blobName)
    {
        CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);

        HashSet<string> blocklist = new HashSet<string>();
        foreach (FileBlock block in GetFileBlocks(fileContent))
        {
            blob.PutBlock(
                block.Id,
                new MemoryStream(block.Content, true),
                null
                );

            blocklist.Add(block.Id);
        }
        blob.PutBlockList(blocklist);
        blob.FetchAttributes();
        blob.Properties.CacheControl = "public, max-age=31536000";
        blob.SetProperties();
        return blob.Uri;
    }

    private IEnumerable<FileBlock> GetFileBlocks(byte[] fileContent)
    {
        HashSet<FileBlock> hashSet = new HashSet<FileBlock>();
        if (fileContent.Length == 0)
            return new HashSet<FileBlock>();

        int blockId = 0;
        int ix = 0;

        int currentBlockSize = MaxBlockSize;

        while (currentBlockSize == MaxBlockSize)
        {
            if ((ix + currentBlockSize) > fileContent.Length)
                currentBlockSize = fileContent.Length - ix;

            byte[] chunk = new byte[currentBlockSize];
            Array.Copy(fileContent, ix, chunk, 0, currentBlockSize);

            hashSet.Add(
                new FileBlock()
                {
                    Content = chunk,
                    Id = Convert.ToBase64String(System.BitConverter.GetBytes(blockId))
                });

            ix += currentBlockSize;
            blockId++;
        }

        return hashSet;
    }

    public void BlobGet(CloudBlobContainer container, string adi, Stream stream)
    {
        CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(adi);
        blob.DownloadToStream(stream);
    }

    public IEnumerable<IListBlobItem> BlobListGet(CloudBlobContainer container)
    {
        return container.ListBlobs();
    }

    public void BlobDelete(CloudBlobContainer container, string adi)
    {
        CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(adi);
        blob.DeleteIfExists();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the exception occurs on that line? That code seems fairly harmless. Could you also post the code for the `SaveAsBlob` method?

Comment: You are right nick_w: Exception thrown at CloudBlobContainer container = helper.ContainerGet(containername); in the SaveAsBlob() method. Any thoughts why?

Comment: Looking at that code, I would say that the exception would have to be on the `helper.BlobAdd` line. If it isn't would you be able to post the code or link to the `BlobHelper` class?

Comment: BlobHelper class upthere. I just wanna remind: image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg); is not throwing exception but I am using breakpoint and hoving over the ms, it says: 'ms.ReadTimeout' and 'ms.WriteTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'. But keeps executing.

Comment: If you are saying that the `ReadTimeout` and `WriteTimeout` properties throw those exceptions when mousing over the `MemoryStream` in debug mode, that is actually OK. There is nothing sinister in those exceptions being thrown, because the debugger accesses them to provide the UI for viewing the object and its properties; it is not necessarily a symptom of a problem.

Comment: I should also point out the `MemoryStream` object does not support the `ReadTimeout` and `WriteTimeout` properties.

Comment: A bit further. container.CreateIfNotExists(); gives the "remote server returned 403". Might be sth to do with permission. I commented out the line, this time container.SetPermissions(containerPermissions); throws an exception

Comment: Check that the account key in your connection string has valid permissions on the account, and also check the value of `blobName` that you are passing into the call to `img.ToStream().SaveAsBlob`.

Comment: I just regenerated the Access Key and replaced with the connection string then it's OK! Thanks for your expertise!

Comment: No problem. I don't have time right now, but do you mind if I post this as an answer?

Comment: Go for it! No problem mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting a 403 error at the call to `container.CreateIfNotExists` or `container.SetPermissions`, ensure that the connection string you are using contains an account key that is valid. You can check this in the Azure portal and regenerate the key and replace the old one in your web/app.config if not.