# Error: Timeouts are not supported on this stream in Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a api controller to recieve bunch of data from a webservice and translate it to a JSON.
When it fetches larger data pack, an error occures:

```
Timeouts are not supported on this stream
```

My controller is pretty simple:

```
public class ChangesPickupController : ApiController
{

    [HttpPost]
    public ChangeStructure[] GetChangesPickup(string id, int page, int toPage, UserInfoStructure uis)
    {
        var manager = new CkpClientManager();

        try
        {
            var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(id, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            using (var client = manager.GetClient())
            {
                return client.GetChanges(uis, dt, page, toPage);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR: " + ex.Message);
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Do you have any clue, what might be a problem? Should I change some attributes for streaming somewhere or what?

Thanks in advance, JiKra

EDIT:

Well, here is my stack:

```
Server stack trace:
at System.IO.Stream.get_ReadTimeout()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.DelegatingStream.get_ReadTimeout()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.DelegatingStream.get_ReadTimeout()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.WebResponseHttpInput.WebResponseInputStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageEncoder.BufferMessageStream(Stream stream, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 maxBufferSize)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageEncoder.ReadMessage(Stream stream, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 maxBufferSize, String contentType)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ReadChunkedBufferedMessage(Stream inputStream)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ParseIncomingMessage(HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage, Exception& requestException)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]:
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
at CkpSelfHost3.CkpWs.ICkpWS.GetChangesPickup(UserInfoStructure UserInfo, DateTime Datum, Int32 Strana, Int32 NaStranu)
at CkpSelfHost3.CkpWs.CkpWSClient.GetChangesPickup(UserInfoStructure UserInfo, DateTime Datum, Int32 Strana, Int32 NaStranu) in C:\Users\krakora\documents\visual studio 20
Host3\CkpSelfHost3\Service References\CkpWs\Reference.cs:line 2576
at CkpSelfHost3.Controllers.ChangesPickupController.GetChangesPickup(String id, Int32 page, Int32 toPage, UserInfoStructure uis) in C:\Users\krakora\documents\visual studio 2
fHost3\CkpSelfHost3\Controllers\ChangesPickupController.cs:line 30
```

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20929384/uploading-file-to-azure-storage-causes-the-error-timeouts-are-not-supported-on

Comment: Absolutely not related. Same error message, different case. I don't use any stream.

Comment: Are you using Azure?

Comment: No, I'm not using Azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem was on the vendor's side in webservice provider.
JiKra